# What is the underlying mechanism for the relaxed memory model in c++ 11?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, memory-model

Say there are two threads, t1 and t2. t1 modifies a global flag f1 and t2 modifies a global flag f2 at around the same time. Following this if t1 tries to read f2 (or t2 reads f1) could it ever read the older value of f2 (or f1)?

This question really isn't about C++ 11 at all. I just want to understand the behaviour of a multi-threaded program with respect to cache coherency and how and why the relaxed model arises and is useful.

Comment: [watch and learn](http://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/)

Comment: You are begging the question. "Following this" presupposes some form of synchronization going on. Absent synchronization, how can you tell whether `t1` reading `f2` happens before or after `t2` writing it?

Comment: I understand that the order is indeterminate. t1 may read f2 after t2 has modified it or before it. Now say t1 modifies f1 while running on core1 and t2 modifies f2 while running on core 2 at comparable times on the two processors. Next suppose t1 accesses f2, i.e. both f1 and f2 stand modified, albeit in the caches of two different cores. Will a read on f2 trigger some coherency enforcement or could t1 still read the older value of f2 because it's not yet written to memory?

Answer (score 3):

Relaxed ordering guarantees only that a thread will never observe an older value of a particular memory location than the newest value that it has observed. If t1 has never observed f2 before the particular read that you mention in the question, it can observe any value that was ever written into f2.

On its own, using `memory_order_relaxed` with a C++11 `std::atomic` is quite weak. It simply guarantees that the read/write is indivisible with respect to other threads: no thread will ever see a partially written (torn) value. Relaxed orderings are really only useful when they interact with other memory operations, or for read-modify-write actions. Read-modify-write actions are guaranteed to read the most recently written value regardless of memory ordering.